# Using accessor with Laravel BackPack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a model named Employee which have an accessor:

```
protected function fullName(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn (mixed $value, array $attributes) => $attributes['name'].' '.$attributes['lastName'],
        );
    }
```

Also I declared `protected $appends = ['full_name'];`

The accessor works perfectly in several cruds, also if I test the accessor:

```
 $empl=\App\Models\Employee::find(200);
 dd($empl->full_name);
```

but when I try to open the Employee CRUD list I get this error:

Undefined array key "name". The error point to the accessor line:

```
get: fn (mixed $value, array $attributes) => $attributes['name'].' '.$attributes['lastName'],'
```

I'm using Laravel 10.21.0.0 and backpack/crud 6.2.0 and backpack/pro 2.0.11

Comment: Can you do `\App\Models\Employee::where('name', null)->get()` ?

Comment: It's returning 0 items I removed  $attributes['name']  and left only $attributes['lastName']  and I get the same error Undefined array key "lastName"

Comment: I don't know. Somehow name is not set there. Try a simple `if(!isset($attributes['name']) { dd($attributes)` }; 
And check why the name is missing. 
Maybe in your crud list operation you are not selecting the `name` column ?

Comment: The thing here is that  if I use any model's field in the accessor  I get the same error, but with the field that I'm using. The error doesn't seems to be related to that field specifically

Comment: Changing to old fashioned accessor: 

public function getFullnameAttribute(): string
    {
        return  $this->name.' '.$this->lastName;
    }
Seems to work correctly. Maybe it's worth testing this on a project from scratch, in case it's a bug? If I have time I'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to old fashioned accessor: public function getFullnameAttribute(): string { return $this->name.' '.$this->lastName; } Seems to work correctly.